# Failing to access getter from object from vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to access an object's getter method which is stored in a vector with no luck. There are no errors when compiling but the program crashes when I try to access the getter.

My object is a class called `Item` and I initialize the vector with a pointer to `Item`.

`vector<Item*> bag = vector<Item*>(someSize);`

The program fails when I try to access the getter like this `std::cout << bag[0]->getID() << std::endl;`

It only happens when it is in the vector and not outside.

Comment: `bag` will contain `someSize` elements initialised to 0, i.e. not valid pointers.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for storing pointers rather than objects? Storing objects would be much simpler, since the vector will create and destroy them for you.

Comment: Because I don't want to initialize objects of the same type over again Mike

Comment: If you declare a `vector` that contains pointers, it won't automatically create the objects for you. Vectors can default-initialise their elements but a pointer default initialises as 0.

Comment: What about the middle case, using the pointer but not the vector? And could you give us a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Jonathan I think I just had an epiphany of what the problem is based off your comment but I am on the train at the moment and can't verify anything yet. Would push_back go to the last element in the vector?

Comment: @Beta It works fine outside the vector and I use push_back to add elements. On the train at the moment so I don't have source code on me at the moment.

Comment: Yes, push_back adds to the end of the vector.  So if you declare a size when you create the vector, and then use push_back, element `[0]` still won't have a valid pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


class Item {
  int ID;
 public:
  int getID() const {return ID;}
  void setID(int myid){ID = myid;}
};

int main(){

  Item *i1 = new Item;
  i1->setID(5);
  std::vector<Item*> bag;
//std::vector<Item*> bag(20);
  bag.push_back(i1);
  std::cout << bag[0]->getID() << std::endl;
  delete i1;
  return 0;
}
```

(Note that `bag` starts out as an empty vector.)

But if I replace the vector definition with the line below it that is commented out, the code will break, because `push_back` adds to the *end* of the vector.  After the `push_back` operation, a vector of size 20 will end up with 21 elements, and the element added via `push_back` is at the end of the vector, not the beginning.

Comment: getID can be a const function.

Comment: pushing back the address of a local variable is dangerous. If the vector is copied to or exists in a larger scope, you will get UB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create the objects somewhere. If `Item()` is simple, you can do something like this:

```
for(auto& item : bag)
{
    item = new Item();
}
```

Then you can call member functions.